# CakePHP Multistep Form Validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm implementing this multistep [form](http://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/09/09/Multistep-forms.html).

In the first step of the form some fields need validating from another Model whose table has hasMany relationship.

`Post hasMany Student`

Fields in first step:

- `Post.contact_person`
- `Post.mobile`
- `Post.email`
- `Student.0.grade`
- `Student.0.gender`

Validation for `Post.` fields are fine, but fields like `Student.0.grade` aren't validated properly that validation always returns true when it shouldn't.

I have to emphasise that validation works perfectly fine in a single page form.

I tried to manually load the Student Model and validate but it seems irrelevant. I suspect it's the array structure making the Student Model not able to find the values to validate. But I'm just not sure how to fix it.

The controller (only the handling part):

```
public function msf_step($stepNumber) {

    $this->set('stepNumber', $stepNumber);

    /**
     * check if a view file for this step exists, otherwise redirect to index
     */
    if (!file_exists(APP.'View'.DS.'Posts'.DS.'msf_step_'.$stepNumber.'.ctp')) {
            $this->redirect('/posts/msf_index');
    }
    /**
     * determines the max allowed step (the last completed + 1)
     * if choosen step is not allowed (URL manually changed) the user gets redirected
     * otherwise we store the current step value in the session
     */
    $maxAllowed = $this->Session->read('form.params.maxProgress') + 1;
    if ($stepNumber > $maxAllowed) {
        $this->redirect('/posts/msf_step/'.$maxAllowed);
    } else {
        $this->Session->write('form.params.currentStep', $stepNumber);
    }

    /**
     * check if some data has been submitted via POST
     * if not, sets the current data to the session data, to automatically populate previously saved fields
     */
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        /**
         * set passed data to the model, so we can validate against it without saving
         */
        $this->Post->set($this->request->data);
        //debug($this->request->data);
        //$this->loadModel('Student');
        //$this->Post->Student->validates();
        //debug($this->request->data);
        //debug($this->Post->Student->validates());
        /**
         * if data validates we merge previous session data with submitted data, using CakePHP powerful Hash class (previously called Set)
         */
        if ($this->Post->validates()) {
            $prevSessionData = $this->Session->read('form.data');
            $currentSessionData = Hash::merge( (array) $prevSessionData, $this->request->data);

            /**
             * if this is not the last step we replace session data with the new merged array
             * update the max progress value and redirect to the next step
             */
            if ($stepNumber < $this->Session->read('form.params.steps')) {
                $this->Session->write('form.data', $currentSessionData);
                $this->Session->write('form.params.maxProgress', $stepNumber);
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'msf_step', $stepNumber+1));
            } else {
                /**
                 * otherwise, this is the final step, so we have to save the data to the database
                 */
                $this->Post->create();
                $currentSessionData['Post']['user_id'] = AuthComponent::user('id');
                //print_r($currentSessionData);
                //die;
                unset($this->Post->Student->validate['post_id']);


                if ($this->Post->saveAssociated($currentSessionData)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved.'), 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-success'));
                    //$this->Session->delete('form');
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-danger'));
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Session->read('form.data');
    }

    /**
     * here we load the proper view file, depending on the stepNumber variable passed via GET
     */
    $this->render('msf_step_'.$stepNumber);
}
```

The view in step 1 (the details are not displayed for simplicity):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('contact_person');
echo $this->Form->input('mobile');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('Student.0.grade', array(
    'options' => array(
        __('1') => __('Grade 1'),               
        __('2') => __('Grade 2'),
        __('3') => __('Grade 3')
    ),
    'empty' => __('Please Select'),
    'div' => 'form-group',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'label' => __('Grade')
));
echo $this->Form->input('Student.0.gender');
echo $this->Form->end('Next step');
```

The array it passes when `$this->request->is('post')` is true:

```
array(
    'Post' => array(
        'contact_person' => 'ABC',
        'mobile' => '123',
        'email' => '123@example.com'
    ),
    'Student' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'grade' => 'Male',
            'gender' => 'Boy'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on cakephp official site:

```
if ($this->ModelName->saveAll(
    $this->request->data, array('validate' => 'only')
)) {
    // validates
} else {
    // does not validate
}
```

I replaced the `$this->Post->Validates()` with the above codes to validates multiple models